# Hosts entry does not take effect

Tags: windows-7, hosts

I am working on windows 7. I have successfully added entries on my hosts file before and it worked fine.

```
10.10.10.10 me.mysite.com
```

But different website was given to me like this (Similar looking):

```
10.135.243.39  tomrkt.h123shb
```

This entry doesn't seem to work.

What I mean by this is:

if i go to `https://10.135.243.39/pkmslogout`, it works.

If I go to `https://tomrkt.h123shb/pkmslogout`, it doesn't work.

I am not sure why that is, can you please shed me some light on this.

Thanks

Comment: Sometimes especially with IE I notice it is necessary to restart the browser after editing the hosts file. Also, can you please clarify exactly what you mean by "it doesn't work".

Comment: Did  you try restarting Windows?

Comment: Does `ping tomrkt.h123shb` return the 10.135.243.39 IP ?

Comment: What you're showing is not a valid domain name;  the HOSTS file requires valid-format domain references.  You'll need to find out the domain extension;  many browsers assume it's ".com" and will append that without showing it to you.  As Hennes says, you'd have to be able to ping it.  You can also verify the connection by using "ping -a 10.135.243.39" to see what the full domain name is associated with that address.

Answer (score 0):

The entries might be cached you could try clearing the cache using:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

or

```
nbtstat -R
```

with Administrator privileges

Comment: Forgot to mention. I tried that too. I flushed the DNS. No luck.

Comment: @user1666952 - Try `nbtstat -R` to also flush netbios cache